# React sometimes rerenders between two setStates, depending on setState order

Tags: reactjs

I've got two simple `useState`s.

At one point, they're set, one after another. This happens within a `useEffect` with `[]` deps.

```
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        if (blob) {
          setBounds([width, height]);
          setUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
        } else console.log("no blob");
      });
```

The above code (first set `bounds`, then `url`) causes the component to rerender **once**, with both states set properly.

However, the code below (first `url`, then `bounds`):

```
      canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        if (blob) {
          setUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
          setBounds([width, height]);
        } else console.log("no blob");
      });
```

makes the component rerender **twice**. The first render has only the `url` set, then only on the second render, the `bounds` are set as well.

Why does changing the order of these two lines change the rerenders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because you're inside a callback function, React isn't batching updates.

So the order of these states being set actually matters and somehow setting the url before the bounds is triggering an additional render which I cannot make out from the given code.